# How can I install the latest version of Tor?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, ppa, proxy, tor

I can't run tor from Iran with obfs3 but when I download the latest version of `Tor Browser` from `https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/4.5.1/tor-browser-linux64-4.5.1_en-US.tar.xz`, it worked correctly. Probably because the last version of tor from `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tor` ppa is `0.2.5.12-1` but the latest version of tor from `https://blog.torproject.org/category/tags/tbb` is `0.2.7.5`.

I don't like to use `Tor Browser`, so how can I install the latest version of tor package?

So, I try option two from `https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu`

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main
```

and

```
$ gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
gpg: requesting key 886DDD89 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: key 886DDD89: "deb.torproject.org archive signing key" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

and

```
$ gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
    OK
```

then

```
$ sudo proxychains  apt-get update
```

and

```
$ sudo proxychains apt-get install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libseccomp2 tor-geoipdb torsocks
Suggested packages:
  mixmaster xul-ext-torbutton socat tor-arm polipo privoxy apparmor-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  deb.torproject.org-keyring libseccomp2 tor tor-geoipdb torsocks
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,490 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,010 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
0% [Working]|DNS-request| us.archive.ubuntu.com 
|DNS-request| deb.torproject.org 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9150-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9150-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
<><>-OK
0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com] [Connecting to deb.torproject.org]|DNS-response| us.archive.ubuntu.com is 91.189.91.14
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9150-<><>-91.189.91.14:80-|DNS-response| deb.torproject.org is 82.195.75.101
0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.14)] [Connecting to deb.torp<><>-OK
<><>-OK
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libseccomp2 amd64 2.1.0+dfsg-1 [34.8 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/ trusty/main deb.torproject.org-keyring all 2014.08.31+b1 [5,268 B]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe torsocks amd64 1.3-3 [73.0 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/ trusty/main tor amd64 0.2.5.12-1~trusty+1 [837 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/ trusty/main tor-geoipdb all 0.2.5.12-1~trusty+1 [540 kB]
Fetched 1,490 kB in 26s (56.7 kB/s)                                            
Selecting previously unselected package libseccomp2:amd64.
(Reading database ... 641228 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libseccomp2_2.1.0+dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libseccomp2:amd64 (2.1.0+dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package deb.torproject.org-keyring.
Preparing to unpack .../deb.torproject.org-keyring_2014.08.31+b1_all.deb ...
Unpacking deb.torproject.org-keyring (2014.08.31+b1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tor.
Preparing to unpack .../tor_0.2.5.12-1~trusty+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tor (0.2.5.12-1~trusty+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package torsocks.
Preparing to unpack .../torsocks_1.3-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking torsocks (1.3-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tor-geoipdb.
Preparing to unpack .../tor-geoipdb_0.2.5.12-1~trusty+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking tor-geoipdb (0.2.5.12-1~trusty+1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up libseccomp2:amd64 (2.1.0+dfsg-1) ...
Setting up deb.torproject.org-keyring (2014.08.31+b1) ...
OK
Setting up tor (0.2.5.12-1~trusty+1) ...
Something or somebody made /var/lib/tor disappear.
Creating one for you again.
Something or somebody made /var/log/tor disappear.
Creating one for you again.
Warning from profile system_tor (/etc/apparmor.d/system_tor) ptrace rules not enforced
Warning from profile system_tor (/etc/apparmor.d/system_tor) signal rules not enforced
Warning from /etc/apparmor.d/system_tor (/etc/apparmor.d/system_tor line 18): profile system_tor network rules not enforced
 * Starting tor daemon...                                                       May 19 19:16:12.263 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
May 19 19:16:12.263 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
May 19 19:16:12.263 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript tor, action "start" failed.
Tor was unable to start due to configuration errors.
Please fix them and manually restart the tor daemon using
 ´service start tor´
Setting up torsocks (1.3-3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up tor-geoipdb (0.2.5.12-1~trusty+1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
```

But still have old version!

```
$ tor -v
May 19 19:16:22.994 [notice] Tor v0.2.5.12 (git-3731dd5c3071dcba) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1f and Zlib 1.2.8.
May 19 19:16:22.994 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
May 19 19:16:22.994 [warn] Command-line option '-v' with no value. Failing.
May 19 19:16:22.994 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Could you please help me to install latest tor package version?

Comment: Did you try `apt-get install tor `, and [configure it](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-unix.html.en#using) ?

Comment: @Serphiroth Yes, I did it and comfigure same as `Tor Browser` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as *tor 0.2.7.5*. What you read about is Tor **Launcher** 0.2.7.5 which I suspect is a different thing that tor itself.

You can have (in decreasing order of stability) the following build:

- the latest stable which **0.2.5.12.1**
- the latest experimental build which is **0.2.6.7.1**
- the latest dev build **0.2.7.1-alpha-dev-20150518T200057Z-1**

none of them will be 0.2.7.5

Comment: Thank you very much, so is there any way to install ` latest experimental build which is 0.2.6.7.1` ?

Comment: Use `deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org tor-experimental-0.2.6.x-trusty main
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org tor-experimental-0.2.6.x-trusty main` in your sources.lsit